# Django filter charfield by greater than X principle

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

Possible duplicate, but no answers so far got any close to the solution.

Imagine you have a charfield like this: `1.1.1.1` arriving in the request.
I.e. basic semantic version.

You need to filter all the objects in the queryset, where their version charfield is greater than this.
For example we have such records in the DB:

```
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.1
1.0.0.0
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
2.2.2.2
```

And in the example provided I gave the version number as `1.1.1.1`.
So filtering by "greater than this" principle we will get only `[1.1.1.2, 2.2.2.2]`.
Right now I'm filtering using packaging.version module from standard library. But can I do this using django ORM?

---

**Update:**
Currently I do it this way:

```
from packaging.version import Version

...

        qs = ApplicationVersion.objects.filter(
            operating_system=user_os.upper()
        )

        valid_versions = [
            i.version,
            for i in qs
            if Version(i.version) > Version(user_app_version)
        ]
```

Comment: Please add what you have right now to the question. You can pass a regex to the ORM

Comment: @IainShelvington I dropped regex because standard library does version comparison for me already.

Comment: Did you try overriding the model class's `__gt__` method?

Comment: @BhavyaPeshavaria no, I didn't yet. Thank you for the suggestion. Will try that.